# Struts send response from AsyncContext

Tags: asynchronous, struts2, long-polling, servlet-3.0

I am trying to do long polling in a struts web application. I start an AsyncContext inside an ActionSupport action method, do some time-consuming work async, and then would like to send the `SUCCESS` response to struts.

I know that I can do `PrintWriter pw = asyncContext.getResponse().getWriter();` and write a raw response, but I would like to somehow signal struts to proceed with the predefined result in struts.xml. Is this possible?

```
<action name="myAction" method="action1" class="myActionClass">
    <result name="success" type="redirectAction">
        /pages/myPage.jsp        <!-- I want to run this from async --->
    </result>
</action>
```

In non-async action I can simply return `SUCCESS` and struts takes care of everything, but I am having trouble with achieving a similar effect with async action. This is what I have so far:

```
public void action1() {
    HttpServletRequest req = ServletActionContext.getRequest();
    HttpServletResponse res = ServletActionContext.getResponse();

    final AsyncContext asyncContext = req.startAsync(req, res);

    asyncContext.start(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // Some time-consuming polling task is done here

            asyncContext.complete();

            // Can I somehow proceed to predefined struts result from here?
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: There is `execAndWait` interceptor - http://struts.apache.org/core-developers/execute-and-wait-interceptor.html.

Answer (score 0):

Currently it seems cannot be done clearly. I am working if I can import this support to Struts but for now, I have a hack which works. I extended `StrutsExecuteFilter` as below:

```java
package me.zamani.yasser.ww_convention.utils;

import org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.PrepareOperations;
import org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsExecuteFilter;
import org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareFilter;
import org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.mapper.ActionMapping;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory;

/**
 * Created by user on 8/31/2017.
 */
public class MYStrutsAsyncExecuteFilter extends StrutsExecuteFilter {
    public final int REQUEST_TIMEOUT = 240000;//set your desired timeout here
    private ExecutorService exe;

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        int size = 41;//set your desired pool size here
        exe = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(
                size,
                new ThreadFactory() {
                    public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
                        return new Thread(r, "My Struts Async Processor");
                    }
                }
        );

        super.init(filterConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(final ServletRequest req, final ServletResponse res, final FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        final HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        final HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

        if (excludeUrl(request)) {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }

        // This is necessary since we need the dispatcher instance, which was created by the prepare filter
        if (execute == null) {
            lazyInit();
        }

        final ActionMapping mapping = prepare.findActionMapping(request, response);

        //if recursion counter is > 1, it means we are in a "forward", in that case a mapping will still be
        //in the request, if we handle it, it will lead to an infinite loop, see WW-3077
        final Integer recursionCounter = (Integer) request.getAttribute(PrepareOperations.CLEANUP_RECURSION_COUNTER);

        if (mapping == null || recursionCounter > 1) {
            boolean handled = execute.executeStaticResourceRequest(request, response);
            if (!handled) {
                chain.doFilter(request, response);
            }
        } else {
            /* I ADDED THESE */
            final AsyncContext context = req.startAsync();
            context.setTimeout(REQUEST_TIMEOUT);

            context.addListener(new AsyncListener() {
                public void onComplete(AsyncEvent asyncEvent) throws IOException {
                }

                public void onTimeout(AsyncEvent asyncEvent) throws IOException {
                    context
                            .getResponse()
                            .getWriter().write("Request Timeout");
                }

                public void onError(AsyncEvent asyncEvent) throws IOException {
                    context
                            .getResponse()
                            .getWriter().write("Processing Error");
                }

                public void onStartAsync(AsyncEvent asyncEvent) throws IOException {
                }
            });
            exe.execute(new ContextExecution(context, mapping));
        }
    }

    private boolean excludeUrl(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return request.getAttribute(StrutsPrepareFilter.class.getName() + ".REQUEST_EXCLUDED_FROM_ACTION_MAPPING") != null;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        exe.shutdown();
        super.destroy();
    }

    class ContextExecution implements Runnable {

        final AsyncContext context;
        ActionMapping mapping;

        public ContextExecution(AsyncContext context, ActionMapping mapping) {
            this.context = context;
            this.mapping=mapping;
        }

        public void run() {
            try {
                execute.executeAction((HttpServletRequest) context.getRequest(),
                        (HttpServletResponse) context.getResponse(), mapping);

                context.complete();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

then

```xml
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2asyncexecute</filter-name>
    <filter-class>me.zamani.yasser.ww_convention.utils.MYStrutsAsyncExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</filter>
```

then put your desired async actions in a specific package and exclude them from Strut's original filter but map them to above filter in your `web.xml`.

I'm working to improve this to be more configurable and clear then import to Struts.

Could you please test in your app? and please feel free to let me know any idea.